# Java - Static Class Private Fields Visible Outside

Tags: java, class, private, encapsulation

In the following simple piece of code, surely this should produce an error, but instead it logs 's' and then '10'. Are private fields not only visible from within their class, even if that class is static?

```
public class Test  {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestClass myObj = new TestClass();

        myObj.test();

        System.out.println(myObj.myField);
    }


    static class TestClass {
        private int myField = 5;

        private void test() {
            System.out.println("s");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How can this be 10? Did you change something and not compile?

Comment: sidenote: your `TestClass` is not private to the `Test` class. It would be visible to every other class within the same package and you could do `new Test.TestClass()` in everwhere.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The fields are all within the `Test` class, so all the classes and fields within `Test` can see each other even when private. Essentially the private keyword says "Only stuff in Test can see me" and in this case everything is in Test.

Comment: How can I make these fields private to `TestClass`?

Comment: Put `TestClass` in a separate file.

Comment: @JoshBambrick You'd have to put them in a different *compilation unit* (file). `private` access means that everything in the same file can see it.

Comment: Do you need to put all classes in a different file then? Or just in specific cases? Can you make a class that is only visible to a specific other class?

Comment: Only by putting those two classes in a package together.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html - just remember that "class" here means outer class, i.e. the class is in the .java file with the same name as the class.

Comment: Is this right then:

 - an inner class can't have private members

 - a separate outer class must be defined in a new file

 - to access a separate outer class, both classes must be in the same package

Comment: An inner class can have private members. The outer class and other inner classes in the same file can see it. Any other classes cannot.

Comment: Private = same file. Normal = same package. Public = Everywhere. Protected = same package and anyone who extends me.